# Does the right half of the rsa public key matter?

Tags: ssh, openssh, pgp, public-key-encryption

In a public key file "id_rsa.pub" generated by ssh-keygen, does the part after the == matter?

I ask because when I changed "root@somedomain.com" to "root", it seems to still work.

More generally, I am curious about what the purpose of that half is.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This right part of a public key (either "id_rsa.pub" or "id_dsa.pub") is just a comment and is usually filled with the < login>@< hostname> who generated the key.
This in a way similar to the comment field from the SSH Public Key File Format (see [RFC 4716](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4716.txt)).

So, as being purely informational and optional, you can change it to whatever you like, but keeping the < login>@< hostname> is a practical way to keep track of what is what.

For more about OpenSSH "authorized_keys" format:

- [OpenBSD sshd man page - "AUTHORIZED_KEYS"](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man8/sshd.8#AUTHORIZED_KEYS_FILE_FORMAT)

Comment: Is there an RFC or similar document for this format as well?
I've seen other funny things in these authorized_keys files as well, such as actual commands.

Comment: This format seems openssh specific... but one of the most widely used. You can find some info about it in the [openssh sshd manpage](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd&sektion=8&arch=&apropos=0&manpath=OpenBSD+Current), in the "AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT" section.

Comment: The openssh sshd manpage is now at [http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sshd(8)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sshd(8))

Comment: OpenSSH reference should be OpenBSD, not FreeBSD. Here is the right man page: [openssh sshd manpage](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man8/sshd.8)

Comment: in Google Cloud Platform, they implemented it in a way that the right part must be the username