# Should 'username@hostname' in a public key be distributed together?

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-keys, public-key-encryption

Usually, at the end of an RSA public key, you find something like 'username@hostname' by default or something else otherwise you specified. It is said that [it is just a comment and doesn't matter at all](https://superuser.com/q/516912/297991).

My question is the following. When I copy and add my public key to a server's `authorized_keys` file, is it necessary to include this part together with the long key string? Or should this part match at all between the server and my local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that by *"send"* you mean adding your public key to your account's `authorized_keys` file.

When adding the key there, it usually makes little sense to use `username@hostname`, as it's clear for what username and host the key is being used.

You better use a more meaningful comment, explaining uses of the key (if you use more keys). If you have just one key, no comment is needed.

Comment: I don't know about the official practice, but the username@host can be a hint of where the key pair is generated (the default behaivor of ssh-keygen). Therefore, it can somehow show who (which source) is accessing that "clear" username and host on the destination machine.